# Force JEditorPane within JScrollPane to shrink + re-wrap

Tags: java, swing, resize, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

Having an issue with a `JScrollPane` expanding its child `JEditorPane` just fine but forcing horizontal scroll bars when resizing it down again (instead of forcing the `JEditorPane` to recalculate wrapping).

The basic flow of code is as follows:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jep);
f.add(jsp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hack, but the best way I could find (without using ugly `ScrollPaneManager`s) was to implement a `ComponentListener` on the `JScrollPane` to resize the child component whenever it was resized.

```
jsp.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        Dimension jspSize = ((JScrollPane)e.getComponent()).getViewport().getSize();
        jep.setBounds(0, 0, jspSize.width, jspSize.height);
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
});
```

Comment: Creating an anonymous ComponentAdapter instead of ComponentListener is simpler because the unused methods don't have to be stubbed in the anonymous class.