# Swing - JEditorPane inside JScrollPane - lines not being "wrapped"

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I have the following class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            // now add it all to a frame
            JFrame j = new JFrame("Test");

            WorkBench right = new WorkBench();

            j.getContentPane().add(right, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());


            // center the jframe, then make it visible
            j.setSize(800, 600);
            j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            j.setVisible(true);
          }
        });
      }


    public static JPanel getPortal()
    {
        JEditorPane swingbox = new JEditorPane();


        swingbox.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());

        swingbox.setOpaque(true);

        swingbox.setContentType("text/html");

      String htmlString = "<html>\n"
         + "<body>\n"
         + "<h1>Welcomfve!  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h1>\n"
         + "<h2>This is an H2 header. sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h2>\n"
         + "<p>This is some sample text  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </p>\n"
         + "<p><a href=\"http://devdaily.com/blog/\">devdaily blog</a></p>\n"
         + "</body>\n";
      swingbox.setText(htmlString);


        swingbox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Heading " );
        title.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        p.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(swingbox, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        return p;
    }

    public static class WorkBench extends JPanel
    {
        private Box current = null;

        public WorkBench()
        {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            current = Box.createVerticalBox();

            //**  Scenario A - no vertical scrolling  **
                add(current, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            //** Scenario B - no line wrapping **
                //JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(current );
                //sp.setViewportView(current );
                //add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        }


        public void addPortal(JPanel portal)
        {
            current.add(portal);

            validate();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to add multiple JPanels, using the `addPortal` method, to the vertical box, which is enclosed in a JScrollPane. The JPanels use the `BorderLayout` and have a `JEditorPane` in the center that displays variable length HTML.

The problem is when I put the vertical box inside the JScrollpane, then the line wrapping of the JEditorPanes stops working. If I add the vertical box without a Jscrollpane, line wrapping works, but, as you expect, no scrolling. How do I get line wrapping + scrolling?

To make things clearer, see the screenshot below:

- In A, I have added the vertical box directly to the JPanel WorkBench.
  Notice that the line wrapping works, but, there is no vertical
  scrolling.
- In B, I have added enclosed the vertical box inside a JScrollPane,
  which I have  added to the JPanel WorkBench. Notice the vertical
  scrollbar is present, but the line wrapping is not working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K49t.png

Comment: any chance of getting a runnable example from you?

Comment: http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html use the approach to determine height for your content html and defined width

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've just moved to a new residence, so sorry for the delay. I will report back soon!

Comment: Added an example. Thanks.

Comment: I found a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968271/force-jeditorpane-within-jscrollpane-to-shrink-re-wrap, but no luck so far getting it to work.

Comment: This looks very promising! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174070/wrapping-html-text-in-a-jeditorpane-inside-a-jscrollpane?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63PHx.jpg

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            // now add it all to a frame
            JFrame j = new JFrame("Test");

            WorkBench right = new WorkBench();

            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            sp.setAutoscrolls(false);

            sp.setViewportView(right);


            j.getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());
            right.addPortal(getPortal());



            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sp.getViewport().setViewPosition(new java.awt.Point(0, 0));
                }
          });


            // center the jframe, then make it visible
            j.setSize(800, 600);
            j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            j.setVisible(true);
          }
        });
      }


    public static JPanel getPortal()
    {
        JEditorPane swingbox = new JEditorPane();


        swingbox.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());

        swingbox.setOpaque(true);

        swingbox.setContentType("text/html");

      String htmlString = "<html>\n"
         + "<body>\n"
         + "<h1>Welcomfve!  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h1>\n"
         + "<h2>This is an H2 header. sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </h2>\n"
         + "<p>This is some sample text  sdsdsdsdsd sdsdsd sdsd sdsd sdsd </p>\n"
         + "<p><a href=\"http://devdaily.com/blog/\">devdaily blog</a></p>\n"
         + "</body>\n";
      swingbox.setText(htmlString);


        swingbox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Heading " );
        title.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        p.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);



        p.add(swingbox, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        return p;
    }

    public static class WorkBench extends JPanel implements Scrollable
    {
        Box vertical_box = null;

        public WorkBench()
        {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            this.vertical_box = Box.createVerticalBox();

            //**  Scenario A - no vertical scrolling  **
                add(this.vertical_box , BorderLayout.CENTER);

            //** Scenario B - no line wrapping **
                //JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(current );
                //sp.setViewportView(current );
                //add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        }

        public void addPortal(JPanel portal)
        {
            this.vertical_box.add(portal);

            validate();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() 
        {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }


        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(
                Rectangle visibleRect,
                int orientation, 
                int direction) 
        {
            return 20;
        }


        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(
                Rectangle visibleRect,
                int orientation, 
                int direction)
        {
            return 60;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() 
        {
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
        {
             if (getParent() instanceof JViewport)
             {
                 return (((JViewport)getParent()).getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height);
             }

             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't Scenario A - "no **horizonal** scrolling"?

Comment: I don't think so, looking at http://i.stack.imgur.com/9K49t.png - line are wrapped, but the is no vertical scrolling?

Comment: It's confusing since line wrap also means "no horizontal scrollbar" (but there might be a vertical one). What happens if you have too many ports to fit on the screen?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. Perhaps this is better? Scenario A: vertical scrollbar is absent and line wrapping is performed. Scenario B: vertical scrollbar is present and but lines are not wrapped to fit the window width. If there are too many ports to fit the screen, then you will only see those that fit, the rest will be off screen.

Answer (score 2):

`JEditorPane` should always resize itself to the exact size necessary to display the text inside. That's why it works with `JScrollPane`: The inner component grows, the scrollpane then asks for the size and configures the scrollbars accordingly.

You don't show us how you create the `JPanel` portals which you try to add. My guess is that there is something wrong with this code. Maybe the `BorderLayout` messes things up.

I suggest you change `JPanel` to `Component` and add the `JEditorPane` without any layout or wrapping component to the panel inside of the `JScrollPane`. That should expose the correct dimensions to the `BoxLayout` and hence size the viewport correctly.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - this got me on the right track. I got the viewport to resize correctly (see example), but now the line wrapping of the JEditorPane is broken. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe if you tell me what "is broken."

Comment: There might be a bug lurking there. Check these posts: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1360537?start=0&tstart=0 and https://community.oracle.com/thread/1352788?start=0&tstart=0 If you find a working solution, please post it here.